# Why Swift Array cannot be altered in property observer didSet?

Tags: arrays, swift, observers, didset

It seems that Swift's Array won't go through didSet, why?

```
var intArray: [Int] = [] {
    didSet {
        intArray += [0]
    }
}

if intArray.count == 0 {
    println("Why is intArray not being altered?")
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`willSet` and `didSet` are **not** invoked when a variable is first initialized, so that's normal behavior, and valid for all property types - being an array makes no difference.

Try this in a playground:

```
var intArray: [Int] = [] {
    didSet {
        intArray += [0]
    }
}

intArray = []

intArray
```

the last statement shows that `intArray` is [0].

Read the 2nd note in [Property Observers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_378)

Comment: Ok but what if I want to sort that array whenever it is updated? I tried in `didSet` but it crashes!! Any suggestion please?